# Excel VBA copying column to column if cells in the column is not empty

Tags: vba, excel, replace, copy

Is there any efficient way or a correct way to copy and paste within the same worksheet? My code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each row In .Rows
            If Not row.Columns("A:A") Is Empty Then   'error here
                .Columns("A:A").Copy .Range("B1")
            End If
        Next rw
        .Columns("A:A").Delete
End With
```

So in the code above, I would like to replace the column B with Column A only when the Column A of the cell is NOT empty. 
For example:

```
1   Nil
    Nil
    24
4   Nil
4   Nil
    12
    3
7   Nil
    2
    Nil
8   Nil
```

Final result will be like this in Column B:

```
1
Nil
24
4
4
12
3
7
2
Nil
8
```

EDIT: Never mind, Solved.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If (.Rows(rw).Columns("A:A").Value <> "") Then
            .Rows(rw).Columns("A:A").Copy .Range("B" & rw)
        End If
    Next rw
    .Columns("A:A").Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    For Each Row In .Rows
        If Row.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
            Row.Cells(1, 2) = Row.Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    Next

    .Columns("A:A").Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the the method when any cell from column changes use the method
Worksheet_Change, Here we are catching any change over the cell in the column J only

In this example we copy the values from the column E to G, without including the empty cells. We clear first the column G if this has any old value using this command **Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").ClearContents**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
idx = ActiveCell.Row
idxStr = CStr(idx)
labelIdx = "J" + idxStr
Dim ii As Long
Dim columnNumber As Long
ii = 1
columnNumber = 10
If ActiveCell.Column = columnNumber And ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") = Range(labelIdx).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").ClearContents

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")
        If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value <> "COLUMN LABEL" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" + CStr(ii)).Value = cell.Value
            ii = ii + 1
        End If

    Next cell

End If

End Sub
```